# Pyinstaller create an executable with external libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, libraries

I am trying to create an executable file (exe) for a Python script that I written in PyCharm.
When I run the script from the PyCharm is working fine but when I try to run it as an individual .py or try to run the exe I am getting an error.

The issue I believe is with the "from infi.devicemanager import DeviceManager" library.

```
from infi.devicemanager import DeviceManager # Used for the retrievement of Device manager information
dm = DeviceManager()
dm.root.rescan()
devs = dm.all_devices # Get all the devices to a list called devs
for d in devs:
    print (d.description)
```

I get following error:

```
PS C:\Python> python.exe .\tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import infi.devicemanager # Used for the retrievement of Device manager information
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'infi'

PS C:\Python> pyinstaller -F .\tests.py

PS C:\Python\dist> .\tests.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'infi'
[15072] Failed to execute script tests
```

Is there a way to include this library to the exe file so anyone without python can run this script?
I am open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

=== UPDATE ===
Full script can be found here
https://github.com/elessargr/k9-serial

Comment: Look at hidden imports section of the docs - https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules

Comment: Use py2exe instead of pyinstaller. If there is a package that it doesn't pick up automatically, you can specify it manually as a resource. But it seems that your main problem is that the devicemanager module is not in the Python's path. Fix this first and then try pyinstaller again.

Comment: import infi should be used instead of from infi.devicemanager import DeviceManager. you dont have to exclusively manage hidden imports

Comment: @buran How do I know the path of this module?

Comment: @Dalen How do I found the devicemanager module path?

Comment: @oetzi I tried that but it doesnt accept it. "import infi" Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python/test.py", line 10, in <module> dm = infi.devicemanager.DeviceManager() AttributeError: module 'infi' has no attribute 'devicemanager'

Comment: If it runs from PyCharm, but not  from cmd (not able to find module `infi`)  you have more than one python installed and you installed `infi.devicemanger` package for the one that is used as interpreter in PyCharm, but not the one invoked from cmd. Sorry, I overlooked that in my initial comment.

Comment: @buran 
I found the interpreters I believe so
C:\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe .\tests.py This is working
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe .\tests.py Doesnt work.
Can I somehow use the ..\venv\Scripts\python.exe for the generation of the exe?

Comment: @ElessarGR, you have virtual environment `venv`. If it workls, then `infi.devicemanager` is installed in the virtual environment. You need to activate the virtual environment and install PyInstaller in it. Then from it run the command to convert to exe. If it still cannot find the external package - try to use `--hiden-import=infi.devicemanager` option

Comment: To see where the module lives you can do: import infi; print(infi.__file__)   or see: import infi; help(infi). I think you have a problem with different interpreters but, also, if the devicemanager is cross-platform module it is possible that it uses dynamic imports to get different modules for different platforms. Such imports are not tracked by pyinstaller or py2exe and imported components must be denoted manually to the (*.exe)fier. You can just make a little module that imports the thing directly like: if 0: import infi.mswindows_driver (or however the thing is called there)

Comment: @buran I wasnt able to find out how to install PyInstaller on the virtual environment.
I will still look around.
https://pastecode.xyz/view/f7e99d48

Comment: @Dalen Can you please elaborate more "You can just make a little module that imports the thing directly like: if 0: import infi.mswindows_driver"? 
https://pastecode.xyz/view/030ffdad

Comment: You put import statements somewhere in your code (maybe in a different module) that are never executed. The py2exe or pyinstaller or whatever, will recognize static import statement and include that module into the *.exe package. It is a dirty trick, but works. You use it when, for some reason, you do not wish to add the resource manually. But you should really ditch the pyinstaller. py2exe will possibly even work with venv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that the interpreter that has `infi.devicemanager` is `C:\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe` as stated by OP in the comments

So there is virtual environment named `venv`. You need to activate the virtual environment and install PyInstaller in it.

```
C:\Python>venv\Scripts\activate
(venv)C:\Python>
```

Note `(venv)` in front of your shell - that means virtual environment `venv` is activated
Now install PyInstaller

```
(venv)C:\Python>pip install pyinstaller
-- here it will install pyinstaller --
```

now you can test that both `pyinstaller` and `infi.devicemanager` are installed in `venv`

`(venv)C:\Python>pip list`

it should list both packages among some others. now

```
(venv)C:\Python>pyinstaller -F C:\Python\tests.py --hidden-import=infi.devicemanager
--here it will create the exe --
```

if I was right it should work now

EDIT: It looks like `infi` is using `__import__(pkg_resources)`, so the command should be

```
(venv)C:\Python>pyinstaller -F C:\Python\tests.py --hidden-import=infi.devicemanager --hiden-import=pkg_resources
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the help! I really appreciate it!
I followed step by step your suggestions and unfortunately nothing.
https://pastecode.xyz/view/76d9c285 This is with venv
https://pastecode.xyz/view/cc0949de This is with normal python (now on both the python .py file can run)
SOO CLOSE and yet soo far :(

Comment: note that it's different error (from the original one) and it's able to find infi.  just add another --hiden-import=pkg_resources or edit the generated spec file. As explained in the docs (the link I shared in comments): __Hidden imports can occur when the code is using `__import__`, `imp.find_module()` or perhaps `exec` or `eval`.__ If you look at the output infi is using `__import__`

Comment: THANK YOU! yup it needed one more --hidden-import! 
I will try to remember this for the future.
Thanks again!

Comment: hi, im using spotdl lib it is working fine when running it from terminal, but when creating .exe file executes successfully but only the spotdl code is not working(it also did not raise any error ) how to solve it ```pyinstaller --collect-data pykakasi --onefile -- --hidden-import=spotdl --noconsole --icon DownloadSPOT.ico -w --add-data "DownloadSPOT.ico;." downloadspot.py``` i have run this command to create .exe file

Comment: @sandeepnegi, please, post your own question, with all relevant information. Asking question in comments will not work.